# Making a div the width of the screen with JQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

I'm making a flat-design UI website and I need a div that stretches completely to the left and right of the browser window.

I've seen an answer that used JQuery, and it half-worked. Only the right side of the div met the right side of the window, and there was a gap at the left side.

**I don't want to use the "left" or "right" CSS properties since setting the "position" to absolute or fixed messes up the flow of the page.**

Thanks.

Comment: Please include your HTML, also, won't `width: 100%` work?

Comment: Hi - just a few questions to start with: Why do you need jquery for this? What have you tried already? Why can't you just set the width to 100% ?

Comment: Can you please provide some code or [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) link for better understanding

Comment: @Frank Provost https://jsfiddle.net/L0bnzmmo/

Comment: @VFXed its not a problem at all. Your body had 8px margin by default. Simply set it to 0

Comment: @FrankProvost I tried width: 100%, but there's still a gap at the left of the div.

Comment: @kiran Thanks! That solved it.

Comment: Nope, there's a gap from the body, like kiran said. https://jsfiddle.net/L0bnzmmo/2/

Answer (score 0):

add the follwing:

```
html, body {
  margin: 0; padding: 0;
  width: 100%; height: 100%;
}
```

Here your fiddle fixed : https://jsfiddle.net/L0bnzmmo/1/

set height width of body and html to 100% and remove paddings and margins which occur by default

Edit: There are plenty of css libarys which you could use to remove this default behaviour which 'seems to be false'. http://purecss.io/ is one example for this.